# Efficient numpy indexing: Take first N rows of every block of M rows

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

I want to grab first 2 rows of array x from every block of 5, result should be:

```
x[fancy_indexing] = [1,2, 6,7, 11,12]
```

It's easy enough to build up an index like that using a for loop.

Is there a one-liner slicing trick that will pull it off? Points for simplicity here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1** Here's a vectorized one-liner using [`boolean-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
x[np.mod(np.arange(x.size),M)<N]
```

**Approach #2** If you are going for performance, here's another vectorized approach using [`NumPy strides`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) -

```
n = x.strides[0]
shp = (x.size//M,N)
out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=shp, strides=(M*n,n)).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [61]: # Inputs
    ...: x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
    ...: N = 2
    ...: M = 5
    ...: 

In [62]: # Approach 1
    ...: x[np.mod(np.arange(x.size),M)<N]
Out[62]: array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12])

In [63]: # Approach 2
    ...: n = x.strides[0]
    ...: shp = (x.size//M,N)
    ...: out=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x,shape=shp,strides=(M*n,n)).ravel()
    ...: 

In [64]: out
Out[64]: array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12])
```

Answer (score 1):

I first thought you need this to work for 2d arrays due to your phrasing of "first N rows of every block of M rows", so I'll leave my solution as this.

You could work some magic by reshaping your array into 3d:

```
M = 5 # size of blocks
N = 2 # number of columns to cut
x = np.arange(3*4*M).reshape(4,-1) # (4,3*N)-shaped dummy input
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1,M)[:,:,:N+1].reshape(x.shape[0],-1) # (4,3*N)-shaped output
```

This will extract every column according to your preference. In order to use it for your 1d case you'd need to make your 1d array into a 2d one using `x = x[None,:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the array to multiple rows of five columns then take (slice) the first two columns of each row.

```
>>> x
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
>>> x.reshape(x.shape[0] / 5, 5)[:,:2]
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]])
```

Or

```
>>> x.reshape(x.shape[0] / 5, 5)[:,:2].flatten()
array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12])
>>>
```

It only works with 1-d arrays that have a length that is a multiple of five.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(1, 16))
y = np.vstack([x[0::5], x[1::5]]).T.ravel()
y
// => array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12])
```

Taking the first `N` rows of every block of `M` rows in the array `[1, 2, ..., K`]:

```
import numpy as np

K = 30
M = 5
N = 2

x = np.array(range(1, K+1))
y = np.vstack([x[i::M] for i in range(N)]).T.ravel()
y
// => array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22, 26, 27])
```

Notice that `.T` and `.ravel()` are fast operations: they don't copy any data, but just manipulate the dimensions and strides of the array.

If you insist on getting your slice using fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np

K = 30
M = 5
N = 2

x = np.array(range(1, K+1))
fancy_indexing = [i*M+n for i in range(len(x)//M) for n in range(N)]
x[fancy_indexing]
// => array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22, 26, 27])
```